# How to convert a string text written in any language to us-english in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some of the records in Português (Brasil) in my Employee table. I want to get all the records on the basis of search parameter "@name" that have similar names with difference of hyphens, like Sergio and Ségio. So when I type Sergio it show me all the names, even the ones with hyphen as Sérgio.

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE firstname like '%@pFirstName%'
```

I am wondering for a solution to convert name parameter to standard us-english language and get the required results.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify an accent insensitive collation to force the accents to be ignored, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE firstname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%@pFirstName%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: Shree, can you please also give me brief about Latin1_General_CI_AI ? Is Collate Latin1_General_CI_AI written at the end is the part of query or it's just a typing error ?

Comment: It's part of the query. By putting that phrase after column name as well as the parameter, you are forcing both to use same collation.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports multiple languages. Information about all the languages are stored in sys.syslanguages system view. You can run following script in Query Editor and see all the information about each language. Information about Months and Days varies for each language.

Syntax:

```
SELECT Alias, * FROM sys.syslanguages
```

Comment: please chack this link :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx

OR
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/setdefaultlanguage/